# disabled javascript in content type form: no javascript

Tags: forms, drupal, wysiwyg

I have a problem in my drupal installation..in the content type page i can't drag and drop lines and i see  two columns :**weight** and **parent** :image1
The problem had application on the  content add form like that: image2
If there any configuration to add or to remove or any help to provide i will be very grateful 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any JS errors in the console? I've known this sort of thing to happen if you include more than one version of jQuery in the page

Comment: It's weired..in my local server everything is fine..but it bugs when i uploded the project to the production server ..

Comment: Here is the firbug errors:TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
[Stopper sur une erreur]  

var collapsed = $.cookie('Drupal.toolbar.collapsed');

toolbar.js?m8e8jg (ligne 29)

TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
[Stopper sur une erreur]  

if ($.cookie('Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight') === null) {

Comment: Did you verify all the files in the misc directory are present?

Comment: yes..the misc directory is OK..i'm wondering if it's a server problem..because in the local server it's ok and not on the remote one

Answer (score 0):

Sorry..
It seemed to be a server configuration problem.. i uploaded a 'virgin' drupal installation to my remote server ( the producton erver) and i installed without any supplement module, just the core modules with the 777 permission for all the files..but the same problem persist ..I'm suspecting the php version that i' m using (5.2.17 instead of 5.3.10)